# Can not find an API to Add/Create new movie at TheMovieDB

Tags: rest, addition, themoviedb-api

I am doing an assessment task with **The Movie Database API** that includes a requirement to make my web app user able to add a new movie by providing title, overview, release date, rating and selecting a poster from the user’s photo gallery.
I can't find any API provided by TheMovieDB that allows the user to create a new movie?

[Link to the documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/introduction)

Comment: I have create a question on The Movie DataBase Support platform and they confirmed that the only way to add new movie is by using their interface and they don't provide any APIs for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a question on **The Movie DataBase Support** platform and they confirmed that the only way to add new movie is by using their interface and they don't provide any APIs for that.

[This is the link to the question thread on TheMovieDB](https://www.themoviedb.org/talk/62bd7a447ef3812769186182?page=1#62bd914b63d93707fef37556)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can't create a new movie from their API, only through the web interface: https://www.themoviedb.org/faq/website (*Section* => **How do I add a title?**)